# How to get Email ID(one value) for each ID for 1st table and then display Email Name from 2nd table as comma Separated in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[What i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZu4Q.png) 
[Results wanted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd7kF.png)From One table , for each ID there can be multiple email id's based on some condition Ex

```
ID  EmailID's
1    Mike.Foster@Mail.com
1    lilly.Foster@Mail.com
2    Michel.Josh@Mail.com
2    Nash.Ted@Mail.com
```

I have to get email Name from these Ids from another table, something like this

Output i Need

```
Email_Name
Foster.Mike,Foster.Lilly
Josh.Michel,Ted.Nash
```

This is what i tried.

```
  SELECT  User_Email = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + User_Email
           FROM table1 b 
           WHERE b.Component_ID= a.Component_ID
           and [Role] ='Team Lead' and Functional_Group ='Product'
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM [WFS].table1 a
GROUP BY table1
```

Now another table i want Email Names

```
 Select EmailNamefrom Table2 where EmailIDs IN ( 'code for Email')
```

Table1 schema

```
ID Component_ID EmailIDs               Role        Functional_Group 
1    1          Mike.Foster@Mail.com   Team Lead    Product
2    1          lilly.Foster@Mail.com  Team Lead    Product
3    2          Michel.Josh@Mail.com   Team Lead    Product
4    2          Nash.Ted@Mail.com      Team Lead    Product
```

Table 2 schema

```
ID  EmailIDs                EmailName
 1   Mike.Foster@Mail.com  Foster.Mike
 2   lilly.Foster@Mail.com Foster.Lilly
```

Any suggestions are welcome.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the E-mails in the very first table really have the same ID, or is that some sort of typo error that you made in your question?

Comment: @Martin They have the same ID, you can say it's Component_ID, not a unique key.

Comment: Is the schema in your question also by any chance incomplete? Like what's the exact schema build that we're supposed to work with? Do you not have a users table containing the names of the users or something? Or are you looking to chop up the emails, using anything before the @-sign as their name? Seems super weird to me honestly.

Comment: you could try use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to achieve what you want. `GROUP_CONCAT(EmailID SEPARATOR ', ') as emails` and add you where conditions etc.

Comment: @Martin Can you please check my updated question.

Comment: Yeah, but please list your tables. Right now I only have your email table. I have no idea where to fetch the "names" that you speak of. Like what table is that? "tbl_names"? etc. also what the schema of that table is. Are the id's coherent between to two tables, in which case you can just do a join based on the table id's and `GROUP_CONCAT()` the names off that? Like judging off the schema you provided contra the sql command you provided, it's pretty clear that a lot of schema information is missing.

Comment: I have to get Email IDs from 1st table based on component_ID concat and then for those Email, i want the Email Name from another table. If there are only 1 component ID , its working fine .  I don't know how to extend for multiple Emailids. Can you mock something up.

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ') as names, emails FROM tbl_names INNER JOIN tbl_emails ON tbl_names.id = tbl_emails.id` for instance. Okay, saw that you updated the schemas now, I'll try to make a full functional sql, 2 sec.

Comment: Ids are not the key here, we have to input emailids to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually close but your SQL doesn't match your schema. This one works as you want:

```
SELECT  Email_Name = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + EmailIDs
           FROM table1 b 
           WHERE b.Component_ID= a.Component_ID
           and [Role] ='Team Lead' and Functional_Group ='Product'
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM table1 a
GROUP BY a.Component_ID;
```

EDIT: I didn't understand what you are asking exactly. Might this be what you meant?

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + EmailName
FROM Table2 where EmailIDs IN ( SELECT EmailIDs
           FROM table1 
           WHERE [Role] ='Team Lead' and Functional_Group ='Product')
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Or you meant this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Component_ID, emailNames
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', '+t2.EmailName
           FROM table2 t2
           INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.EmailIDs = t2.EmailIDs
           WHERE t1.Component_ID = Table1.Component_ID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
 ) t(EmailNames)
WHERE [Role] ='Team Lead' and Functional_Group ='Product'
```

Here is [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b26e8/1)

Comment: Now i want to input these email_name in another table and get emailNames for each record .For each row there are multiple emailIds to be converted to emailName.And EmailNames also i want as comma seperted in same column.

Comment: @GeekyNerd, sorry I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you should show what you want as a sample output. (and probably you are already aware what a weird schema you have)

Comment: 2 secs, i am adding image for the question i asked, please check it.

Comment: @GeekyNerd, I don't like checking images, I prefer code.

Comment: Can you please check image, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @GeekyNerd, I still can't see what is different in your image. Did you try the second SQL in the EDIT?

Comment: I want ouput like this EmailName
                                 Foster.Mike,Foster.Lilly
                                 Josh.Michel,Ted.Nash

Comment: @GeekyNerd, output is like that. Anyway I am adding another sample, maybe that is what you mean.

Comment: i have mocked something like this, can you please help

Answer (score 0):

***Disregard this answer as I found out that `GROUP_CONCAT()` is a MySQL specific function***, which means it won't work in SQL Server, however, I'll let it stay for future references.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(EmailName SEPARATOR ', ') as name
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.EmailIDs=table2.EmailIDs
WHERE
  table1.EmailIDs=table2.EmailIDs
GROUP BY
  table1.Component_ID
```

Output:

Foster.Mike, Foster.Lilly

Ted.Nash, Josh.Michel

Working [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6001a/3)

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: SQL server doesn't have Group_Concat, does it?

Comment: After a search I found out that it doesn't, unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need `CTE` with `STUFF()` :

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT t1.*, t2.emailname
     FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
          table2 t2
          ON t2.emailids = t1.emailids 
)

SELECT id, STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT ','+t1.emailname
                    FROM t t1
                    WHERE t1.id = t.id
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                   ), 1, 1, ''
                 ) AS Email_Name
FROM t
GROUP BY id;
```